# query to get top 10 values for every month and year- (Ms access)

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have following database structure (Data is not real)

```
+------------+-------+-------------+
|   Datum    | Dauer | description |
+------------+-------+-------------+
| 11.01.2018 | 02:30 | Test        |
| 11.02.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.02.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.03.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.03.2018 | 03:30 | Test        |
| 11.03.2018 | 02:30 | Test        |
| 11.04.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.04.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.05.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.05.2018 | 01:00 | Test        |
| 11.05.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.06.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.06.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.06.2018 | 02:30 | Test        |
| 11.06.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.07.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.07.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.07.2018 | 03:30 | Test        |
| 11.08.2018 | 05:30 | Test        |
| 11.08.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.08.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.08.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.08.2018 | 02:30 | Test        |
| 11.08.2018 | 00:30 | Test        |
| 11.09.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
| 11.09.2018 | 02:30 | Test        |
| 11.09.2018 | 01:30 | Test        |
+------------+-------+-------------+
```

I would like to create a query to get top 10 values from each month and order by month and time.

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT Top 10 *
FROM History_query where Month(Datum)=1 and Dauer >= #01:00# order by  Dauer desc 
Union 
SELECT Top 10 *
FROM History_query where Month(Datum)=2 and Dauer >= #01:00# order by Dauer desc
```

the thing is i have to write a 12 times the union query for every month and for year 2019 the same.

there has to another way to make it simpler.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM History_query 
WHERE Dauer IN
    (SELECT Top 10 Dauer
    FROM History_query As T
    WHERE Year(T.Datum) = Year(History_query.Datum)
        AND Month(T.Datum) = Month(History_query.Datum)
        AND T.Dauer >= #01:00#
    ORDER BY Dauer desc)
```

**Edit**:

You could try using a helper query:

```
SELECT 
    Year([Datum]) * 100 + Month([Datum]) As YearMonth, 
    Dauer
FROM 
    History_query 
WHERE
    Dauer >= #01:00#
```

Save this as *YMHistory*. Then use this in the final query:

```
SELECT *
FROM YMHistory
WHERE Dauer IN
    (SELECT Top 10 Dauer
    FROM YMHistory As T
    WHERE T.YearMonth = YMHistory.YearMonth
    ORDER BY Dauer desc)
```

Comment: the query works but i have performance issue. It take 30 sec to get the result from 5000 records. is there any way to make it better as performance point of view.

Comment: You could assign field _Dauer_ an index.

Comment: i have index the column as `Yes (Duplicates OK)` still it takes 20 sec to run. any other input. thanks.

Comment: Try using a helper query. See edited answer, please.

Comment: now it works . now it takes around 4 sec which is good . thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.